Can the trace be computed in any Schauder basis?
I'm cross-posting this question from Math.SE, as it didn't get much attention there.
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T \in L(H)$ a trace-class operator. It is well known that the trace of $T$, given by $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_n \langle Te_n, e_n\rangle$ for some orthonormal Hilbert basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, is independent of the chosen orthonormal basis and even independent of the order of summation.
In finite dimensions, however, we can represent $T$ as a matrix using any basis, not necessarily orthonormal, and summing the diagonal yields the trace. Thus, one might expect a similar result to hold for arbitrary trace-class operators.
Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is an ordered Schauder basis for $H$, and let $\pi_n$ denote the linear functional on $H$ that selects  out the coefficient of $f_n$, e.g., $\pi_1(\alpha_1f_1 + \alpha_2 f_2 + \cdots) = \alpha_1$. If $T$ is trace class, do we have $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_n \pi_n(Tf_n)$? If so, is the sum always independent of order? If the suggested formula fails in general, what if we restrict to unconditional or symmetric Schauder bases?

Which kind of projection do you mean? Orthogonal? Or with respect to the given basis? Next, your formula looks weird, as the trace is a number and the projection must be vector-valued, hence the right hand side is a vector.

@Nandor I have edited the post to clarify what I mean by $\pi_n$. The formula I have given is then just the trace formula in the finite-dimensional case (extended to Schauder bases), no?

You might want to look at G.L. Litvinov, "On the traces of linear operators in locally convex spaces" Sel. Math. Sovietia , 8 : 3 (1989) pp. 203–212 Trudy Sem. Vekt. i Tenz. Anal. , 19 (1979) pp. 243–272
